# VLC cannot read videos on Pi-4 with RPi-OS

Tags: pi-4, vlc

I just bought a RPi-4, installed the official Raspberry pi OS, and discovered that VLC cannot read .mp4 videos encoded with H264. VLC can play the sound but not the video. I can only play the videos through Chromium web browser and mplayer. VLC version in the about menu is 3.0.12 (the command "apt show vlc" says 3.0.12-0+deb10u1+rpt2), and my Pi OS realease is "Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)".

Here is an example media information that i cannot read :

> Stream 0
> Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
> Type: Video
> Video resolution: 1278x678
> Buffer dimensions: 1278x678
> Frame rate: 15
> ...

In fact i realize VLC cannot even play Xvid (.avi) and JPEG motion Video (.mov). I can only play .mp3 files with VLC. I tried another player, MXPlayer or something like that but it was even worst.

Right now i do not see anything in VLC's messages but yesterday it was saying something like this when trying to play .mp4 (H264) videos:

> main error : buffer deadlock prevented

I guess this should be a known bug but i cannot find any information about anyone having the same problem... Does anyone has any idea of what this problem is and how to solve it?

Thank you very much,

Joe

Comment: I've been using VLC for years and never had such issues. Post the exact version of VLC you have, the Pi OS release, and make sure the video output in VLC is set to "automatic".

Comment: VLC version in the about menu is 3.0.12 (the command "apt show vlc" says 3.0.12-0+deb10u1+rpt2), and my Pi OS realease is "Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)". And yes, the video output is set to auto. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. I advise you to try out sample videos from the [ffmpeg test collection](https://samples.ffmpeg.org/). Then you can post links to specific videos that don't work.

Comment: Thanks, i just downloaded a raspbian image from raspberrypi.com instead of using the one that was downloaded automatically from the imager tool and now everything works. I don't know what was the problem.